# SQL find rows that have same value for one column and different values in other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find rows that share the same column but also have different values in other columns.  I have created a SQL Fiddle for reference.  My result is still 0.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tracking` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IP` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `MAC` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `UUID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `isActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tracking`
--

INSERT INTO `tracking` (`id`, `IP`, `MAC`, `UUID`, `timestamp`, `isActive`) VALUES
(1, '98.186.154.212.12', '10:DD:B1', ' uuid:a5fadbbd ', '2016-09-06 15:03:52', 0),
(2, '423.2362.234', '2534623523523', ' uuid:a5fadbbd ', '2016-09-06 15:15:28', 0),
(3, '98.186.154.212.12', '10:DD:B1', ' uuid:a5fadbbd ', '2016-09-06 15:03:52', 0),
(4, '98.186.154.212.12', '10:DD:B1', ' uuid:a5fadbbd ', '2016-09-06 15:04:09', 0),
(5, '98.186.154.212.12', '10:DD:B1', ' uuid:a5fadbbd ', '2016-09-06 15:04:44', 0),
(6, '98.186.154.212.12', '10:DD:B1', ' uuid:a5fadbbd ', '2016-09-06 15:04:44', 0),
(7, '98.186.154.212.12', '10:DD:B1', ' uuid:a5fadbbd ', '2016-09-06 15:06:28', 0),
(8, '98.186.154.212.12', '10:DD:B1', ' uuid:a5fadbbd ', '2016-09-06 15:06:28', 0),
(9, '98.186.154.212.12', '10:DD:B1', ' uuid:a5fadbbd ', '2016-09-06 15:06:28', 0);


SELECT * 
    FROM tracking t 
    WHERE timestamp = 
         ( SELECT MAX(timestamp) 
           FROM tracking
           WHERE UUID = t.UUID 
              AND (IP <> t.IP OR MAC <> t.MAC)) 
    GROUP BY id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0ae3b6/4

The desired result would look like this:

Comment: You should include data and code samples in the question.  SQL Fiddle is a great nice-to-have, but it doesn't substitute for a well-written question.  For instance, SQL Fiddle can be down.  Also, desired results would be helpful.

Comment: Isn't this the same question you posted earlier and deleted?

Comment: Have you tried to write a query? Post it.

Comment: Query edited into post

Comment: He got the query from the answer to the deleted question.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for being so helpful

Comment: Why did you delete the question instead of just improving it there? Where are the desired results?

Comment: Your query does more than just find rows with same and different columns. What is the `MAX(timestamp)` for?

Comment: It is to find the rows with the latest timestamps...That part is not important.  I simply need results where UUID and IP are different while still sharing the same UUID.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what `MAX(timestamp)` has to do with the question. If you just want to find rows that match in one column and differ in others, you can use a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM tracking AS t1
JOIN tracking AS t2 
ON t1.uuid = t2.uuid
 AND (t1.ip != t2.ip OR t1.mac != t2.mac)
 AND t1.id < t2.id
```

The extra `t1.id < t2.id` condition prevents getting duplicates with `t1` and `t2` swapped.

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0ae3b6/11)

Comment: The op has 2 accounts. We are but cannon fodder http://stackoverflow.com/q/39352884